# How to insert a matrix in the middle of another (increasing size) while maintaining row-column relationships between elements of old matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix A,

```
A=[
   a 0 0 b
   0 c d 0
   0 e f 0
   g 0 0 h
  ]
```

I would like to have an efficient and general way to add some size (say 2x2) identity matrix at some specified index along the diagonal, say after c, while maintaining all of the relationships between the elements shown in A. The final matrix should be

```
B=[
   a 0 0 0 0 b
   0 c 0 0 d 0
   0 0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 0 1 0 0
   0 e 0 0 f 0
   g 0 0 0 0 h
  ]
```

I've tried block_diag in scipy.linalg, but I'm not able to find a way to get that to work

Comment: How is your matrix implemented? Is it in the form of nested lists? Then all you need is to give 2 arguments to a function (for offset) that will manually add insert, say, 2 zero rows, then insert the identity matrix columns by inserting either zeros or ones (depending on where it is inserted) into the nested lists.

Comment: Start with `np.zeros((6,6))` and copy blocks of `A` to it.  Alt. use `np.insert` to add the middle rows and columns.  It may look prettier but won't save any copying

Comment: the index is a parameter or you always want to insert the identity matrix in the center?